# How to show multiple horizontal recyclerview like shopping app..?

Tags: android, gridview

I am fetching data and showed in gridview using cardview.I want to show multiple grid Item horizontally like shopping app I was refered many sites but i can't understand to implement becz some said to use viewpager but I can't understand how to implement this..Bcz of I am bigginerr please suggest me..
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you might be seeking something like this.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Just use Horizontal LinearLayoutManager on your recycler views.